# How to activate HD indicator lights on Dell PowerEdge 710 in Linux

Tags: linux, zfs, dell-poweredge, proxmox

I have a particular drive that is failing (`/dev/sdb`)

I need to replace the failed drive but I am not sure which it is... I should have documented what drives were in what slots and what their devs were but I did not and it will be very troublesome should I need to shut it down.

I am running proxmox on the metal and the drive is part of a ZFS Pool. I would ideally have a command to make a particular dev identifier flash.

Comment: contact the Dell support, they have a very reliable and fast response. If this device is EOL or EoS then you may have to ask on superuser.com

Comment: It is both EoL and EoS

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Sometime Dell workers grant you a free Tipp howto solve that

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a iDRAC on that dell server?
if you do, do an run an `lshw -class disk` in the prompt, find the serial number on your drive. Log in to idrac and turn the light on.